# Pull Title attribute with out .get("title")

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having value like

```
<a href="/for-sale/property/abu-dhabi/page-3/" title="Next" class="b7880daf"><div title="Next" class="ea747e34 ">
```

I need to pull out only ""Next" from title="Next" for the one i used

```
soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"}).get('title')
```

is there any method to get the tittle value with out using **.get("title")**

My code

```
next_page_text = soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"}).get('title')
```

Output:

```
Next
```

I need:

```
next_page_text = soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"})
```

Output:

```
Next
```

Please let me know if there is any method to find.

Comment: Based on your html you have to use `soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"}).get('title')` or `soup.find('a',attrs={"title": "Next"})['title']` since you are trying to get the value from attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get Next.Try this. Using `find`() or `select_one`() and Use If to check if element is present on a page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res=requests.get("https://www.bayut.com/for-sale/property/abu-dhabi/page-182/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
if soup.find("a", attrs={"title": "Next"}):
  print(soup.find("a", attrs={"title": "Next"})['title'])
```

If you want to use css selector.

```
if soup.select_one("a[title='Next']"):
   print(soup.select_one("a[title='Next']")['title'])
```

Comment: i tried both but getting below error <ipython-input-169-66990b239473> in parse_page(url)
      7 #        print(soup)
      8 
----> 9         next_page_text = soup.select_one("a[title='Next']")['title']
     10         print(next_page_text)
     11         if next_page_text == 'Next':

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: @Amar just copy my entire code and execute.You should get next as  I am getting.

Comment: for all the pages above logic works fine, for last page logic not working

Comment: can you share the last page link?

Comment: please find below code **from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res=requests.get("https://www.bayut.com/for-sale/property/abu-dhabi/page-182/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
print(soup.find("a",attrs={"title" : "Next"})['title'])**

Comment: @kunduKgetting the same issue

Comment: Your results return correct since last page you don't have next page tag then how would  you get the element.

Comment: correct, but not able handle this situation is the problem

Comment: do you any other solution to handle this situation?

Comment: @Amar : Check the updated answer.Just use if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm re-writing my answer as there was confusion in your original post.

If you'd like to take the URL associated with the Next tag:

```
soup.find('a', title='Next')['href']
```

['href'] can be replaced with any other attribute in the element, so title, itemprop etc.

If you'd like to select the element with Next in the title:

```
soup.find('a', title='Next')
```

Comment: i tried **next_page_text = soup.find('a')['title']** but got different value from the page like **Bayut.com UAE Property Portal** but i need only **Next from tittle** from code **<a href="/for-sale/property/abu-dhabi/page-3/" title="Next" class="b7880daf"><div title="Next" class="ea747e34 ">**

Comment: So you want to pull the element next page if the title is next? or you want to pull the data stored in the "Title" tag?